# Incorrect Javascript Day When Added?

Tags: javascript, date

I have a javascript function that takes in a number `X` and a date, and returns a new `Date` that is `X` number of days away:

```
function addDays(theDate, numDaysToAdd) {
    var newDate = new Date();
    return new Date(newDate.setDate(theDate.getDate() + numDaysToAdd));
}
```

I pass it a day that is `Sat Jul 02 2016 16:03:06 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)` and a number `7`, but the result I got was `Thu Jun 09 2016 16:05:32 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)`. Why is it giving me the correct date but wrong month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `newDate` is always created from the current date (`new Date()`). In other words, if this function is executed in June it will produce a date in June, then try to set a the day of the month as a offset from the input date.

You need to construct `newDate` as a copy of `theDate`:

```js
function addDays(theDate, numDaysToAdd) {
    var newDate = new Date(theDate);
    newDate.setDate(theDate.getDate() + numDaysToAdd);
    return newDate;
}

var d = new Date('Sat Jul 02 2016 16:03:06 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)');
console.log(addDays(d, 7).toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add number of milliseconds to given date and it will generate correct date.

> `getTime()` returns milliseconds from `epoch`.
>
> offset = numDaysToAdd * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
>
> 24: Hours in a day
>
> 60: Minutes in an hour
>
> 60: seconds in a minute
>
> 1000: milliseconds in a second
>
> `Date` constructor takes milliseconds from epoch

```
function addDays(theDate, numDaysToAdd) {
    var start = theDate.getTime();
    var offset = numDaysToAdd * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    return new Date(start + offset);
}

var today = new Date();
console.log(today, addDays(today, 10));
```